# How do I add username / password authentication information in a HtmlUnit test case?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am accessing an svn repository via http protocol.  When I put in the url into Internet Explorer, it prompts me with a dialog box for username / password and then the file loads up correctly in the browser.

What I need to do is download a ton of files from different tags from this svn repository.  I was trying to automate downloading these files using HtmlUnit.  Unfortunately it gives me the "401 Authorization Required ..." error.  I don't know how to set the userid /password information in my HtmlUnit test.

Can a kind soul help me out with this please?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like:

```
DefaultCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
    (DefaultCredentialsProvider) webClient.getCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.addCredentials("username", "password");
//OR
credentialsProvider.addNTLMCredentials("username", "password", null, -1, "localhost", "domain");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use IE or a web browser? You can install svn or [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.org/download/) and checkout the entire repository with svn, even with the http protocol.

Comment: I do have TortoiseSVN, but I need to automate downloading a BUNCH of files from different tags.  Couldn't get to automate TortoiseSVN.  Thats why I needed this.  
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You could set up multiple directories to the same repository, but a different directory for each different tag/branch needed. If you need to automate the process, it might be possible with the svn command line tools using batch or powershell.

Comment: I've had to do this before and I agree with @Ryan. When possible, it's much easier to use the command line version of the svn tool.  I believe there is one available on sourceforge or colabnet for windows and for unix/linux.